# Handling key event doesn't register until other key event is triggered, using Crossterm

Tags: rust, crossterm

I just started Rust and wanted to make a simple and easy project that could help me learn more about the language.

I'm making an interactive Todo app in the terminal using Crossterm. Everything was going fine, until I encountered this really strange behavior. I want 2 different "tabs", one tab to keep track of the tasks which need to be done, and the other for the tasks which are completed. I also want to be able to cycle through the tasks, so that later you can edit them and modify the elements.

I'm using the <kbd>Tab</kbd>  key event to toggle between the two different tabs, TODO and DONE, which is done by setting the contents of a mutable variable, `curr_tab`. It works on the first <kbd>Tab</kbd> press, but after that, the only way to switch is to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then the up arrow, but will switch back after the next arrow key input.

I make a mutable variable like so:

```rust
let mut curr_tab = Action::DONE;
```

And use it like so:

```rust
list.print_header(&curr_tab);
list.print_list(&curr_tab, index);
```

Here's the code I use to handle keys:

```rust
if let Event::Key(event) = read()? {
    match event.code {
        KeyCode::Up => index = index.checked_sub(1).unwrap_or(0),
        KeyCode::Down => index = min(index + 1, curr_vec.len() - 1),
        KeyCode::Tab => {
            curr_tab = match curr_tab {
                Action::TODO => Action::DONE,
                Action::DONE => Action::TODO,
            }
        },
        KeyCode::Char('q') => break,
        _ => continue,
    }
}
```

This `read` call is in a non-blocking poll, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Here's a gist to the entire code if you care to reproduce it: [gist](https://gist.github.com/joeymalvinni/3680b70e7b64684bc27d08443d5093cb)

Any help is appreciated.